# trouble using growingtextview library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I'm using a cocoa pod library called growingtextview and I'm having trouble implementing it. There seems to be an issue with some constraints but I can't identify them. If anyone has used this library before and could help with implementation it'd be greatly appreciated. Also if you know any similar libraries or methods on achieving this please let me know.

Growing Text View
https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView

Code for library

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

@objc public protocol GrowingTextViewDelegate: UITextViewDelegate {
@objc optional func textViewDidChangeHeight(_ textView: GrowingTextView, height: CGFloat)
}

@IBDesignable @objc
open class GrowingTextView: UITextView {

// Maximum length of text. 0 means no limit.
@IBInspectable open var maxLength: Int = 0

// Trim white space and newline characters when end editing. Default is true
@IBInspectable open var trimWhiteSpaceWhenEndEditing: Bool = true

// Maximm height of the textview
@IBInspectable open var maxHeight: CGFloat = CGFloat(0)

// Placeholder properties
// Need to set both placeHolder and placeHolderColor in order to show placeHolder in the textview
@IBInspectable open var placeHolder: NSString? {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}
@IBInspectable open var placeHolderColor: UIColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0) {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}
@IBInspectable open var placeHolderLeftMargin: CGFloat = 5 {
    didSet { setNeedsDisplay() }
}

override open var text: String! {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

fileprivate weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

// Initialize
override public init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
    super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
    commonInit()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
}

open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: 30)
}

func associateConstraints() {
    // iterate through all text view's constraints and identify
    // height,from: https://github.com/legranddamien/MBAutoGrowingTextView
    for constraint in self.constraints {
        if (constraint.firstAttribute == .height) {
            if (constraint.relation == .equal) {
                self.heightConstraint = constraint;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Listen to UITextView notification to handle trimming, placeholder and maximum length
fileprivate func commonInit() {
    self.contentMode = .redraw
    associateConstraints()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidChange, object: self)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidEndEditing), name: NSNotification.Name.UITextViewTextDidEndEditing, object: self)
}

// Remove notification observer when deinit
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

// Calculate height of textview
private var oldText = ""
private var oldWidth = CGFloat(0)
override open func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if text == oldText && oldWidth == bounds.width { return }
    oldText = text
    oldWidth = bounds.width

    let size = sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let height = maxHeight > 0 ? min(size.height, maxHeight) : size.height

    if (heightConstraint == nil) {
        heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: height)
        addConstraint(heightConstraint!)
    }

    if height != heightConstraint?.constant {
        self.heightConstraint!.constant = height;
        scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
        if let delegate = delegate as? GrowingTextViewDelegate {
            delegate.textViewDidChangeHeight?(self, height: height)
        }
    }
}

// Show placeholder
override open func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    if text.isEmpty {
        guard let placeHolder = placeHolder else { return }
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment

        let rect = CGRect(x: textContainerInset.left + placeHolderLeftMargin,
                          y: textContainerInset.top,
                          width:   frame.size.width - textContainerInset.left - textContainerInset.right,
                          height: frame.size.height)

        var attributes: [String: Any] = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: placeHolderColor,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
        ]
        if let font = font {
            attributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
        }

        placeHolder.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: attributes)
    }
}

// Trim white space and new line characters when end editing.
func textDidEndEditing(notification: Notification) {
    if let notificationObject = notification.object as? GrowingTextView {
        if notificationObject === self {
            if trimWhiteSpaceWhenEndEditing {
                text = text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                setNeedsDisplay()
            }
        }
    }
}

// Limit the length of text
func textDidChange(notification: Notification) {
    if let notificationObject = notification.object as? GrowingTextView {
        if notificationObject === self {
            if maxLength > 0 && text.characters.count > maxLength {

                let endIndex = text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: maxLength)
                text = text.substring(to: endIndex)
                undoManager?.removeAllActions()
            }
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Below is my implementation

```
import UIKit
import GrowingTextView

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextViewDelegate, GrowingTextViewDelegate {


func textViewDidChangeHeight(_ textView: GrowingTextView, height: CGFloat) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}



var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

func setupKeyboardObservers() {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func handleKeyboardNotification(_ notification: Notification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue
        print(keyboardFrame as Any)


        let isKeyboardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow
        let isKeybobardNotShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide


        bottomConstraint?.constant = isKeyboardShowing ? -keyboardFrame!.height : 0



        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (completed) in


        })
    }
}

deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}


let containerView: UIView = {
    let cView = UIView()
    cView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return cView
}()




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.title = "Search Bar"
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    setupKeyboardObservers()

    automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    let textView = GrowingTextView()
    textView.delegate = self 


    view.addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.addSubview(textView)

    containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

    NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.1, constant: 0).isActive = true



    NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0).isActive = true

    bottomConstraint =   NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)


    view.addConstraint(bottomConstraint!)


    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-10-[v0]-10-|", views: textView)
    containerView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-10-[v0]-10-|", views: textView)

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    textView.maxLength = 0
    textView.trimWhiteSpaceWhenEndEditing = false
    textView.placeHolder = "Say something..."
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    textView.placeHolderColor = UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)
    textView.maxHeight = 70.0
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0





//        //Looks for single or multiple taps.
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")

    //Uncomment the line below if you want the tap not not interfere and cancel other interactions.
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
 //        
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)



//    //Calls this function when the tap is recognized.
func dismissKeyboard() {
    //Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.
    textView.endEditing(true)
    }





}

}

extension UIView {
func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views : UIView...) {


    var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()

    for(index, view) in views.enumerated(){
        let key = "v\(index)"
        viewsDictionary[key] = view
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }
    addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))

}
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Output

2017-05-29 01:55:26.544 searchBar_v4[53924:5226357] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 10
2017-05-29 01:55:26.656157-0400 searchBar_v4[53924:5226357] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
"",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Comment: Please paste only the relevant code with the exact error. Going through the entire implementation is tedious.

Comment: It's a SIGABRT error and only occurs once the keyboard is dismissed.

Comment: There are no errors in the code. The compiler says it's a constraint issue but I don't see any problems.

Comment: SIGBART is not the actual error. How did you know constraints was the issue ? Paste that error in the question.

Comment: I read the output. I'll include it in an edit in the question.